# TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image

Tags: php, magento, tcpdf

We are using a extension for Magento which generates PDFs for orders based on php (phtml) templates.

I've customised it a bit and am getting the bellow error

> a:5:{i:0;s:149:"TCPDF ERROR: [Image] Unable to get the size of the image: http://example.com/skin/frontend/my-package/default/images/packing-slip-logo.jpg";i:1;s:1193:"#0 /var/www/example/lib/tcpdf/tcpdf.php(6884): TCPDF->Error()

This is how I'm adding the image:

```
<img width="900" style="width: 900px; margin: 0; padding: 0" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('skin'); ?>frontend/my-package/default/images/packing-slip-logo.jpg" />
```

Am I missing something obvious on how I should add the image?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is because of double quotes in your code. 
change this

```
<img width="900" style="width: 900px; margin: 0; padding: 0" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('skin'); ?>frontend/my-package/default/images/packing-slip-logo.jpg" />
```

this;

```
echo"<img width='900' style='width: 900px; margin: 0; padding: 0' src='".Mage::getBaseUrl('skin')."'frontend/my-package/default/images/packing-slip-logo.jpg' />
```

if you want to use double quotes in writehtml part you have to use escape character like this \"

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this helps.

```
<img width="900" style="width: 900px; margin: 0; padding: 0" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl('skin').'frontend/my-package/default/images/packing-slip-logo.jpg'; ?>" />
```